# if I delete Category from Magento 1.9.2.4, will it affect at google indexing or search ranking?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.2.2, magento1.9.2.4

I want to delete a category along with it's subcategory. I have assigned 500 products on this category and subcategory. I have some queries.

1. If I delete category and subcategories. will it affect on google indexing and google search ranking.
2. will it affect performance and urls related issue such 404 errors or broken links

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. It will give impacts on our search ranking. You can simply check this fact.  If you have decent traffics from the category and subcategory. Deleting the category will give you negative SEO impact since you are losing organic search traffic. If the category is not attracting website traffics, it won't give any negative impacts for your website SEO. 
   Please make sure to check category landing traffic through either google analytic or google search console.

2.After you delete the link, make sure redirect the deleted link.
-Log in Magento Admin Panel
-Under “Catalog” in the top navigation, click on “URL Rewrite Management
From there, you can redirect deleted URL. 
*FYI 404 errors give you negative impacts on your google seo score.

Comment: Thank you for giving me valuable information, if i disable those categories and subcategories, despite of, will it impact on search ranking

Comment: Yes, It will. Because you are losing traffics from those categories.